# EDI to xml transformation using smooks

Tags: apache-camel, edi, smooks

I tried to convert a file containing EDI message to xml using **org.milyn.smooks.camel.processor.SmooksProcessor** which implements **org.apache.camel.Processor** interface. The directory containing the file is set as camel source endpoint. But while trying to parse the message, some error occurs and **SmooksException** is thrown as follows :

> org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
>       at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:97)[milyn-smooks-core-1.5.1.jar:]
>       at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:64)[milyn-smooks-core-1.5.1.jar:]
>       at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:526)[milyn-smooks-core-1.5.1.jar:]
>       at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:482)[milyn-smooks-core-1.5.1.jar:]
>       at org.milyn.smooks.camel.processor.SmooksProcessor.process(SmooksProcessor.java:95)[milyn-smooks-camel-1.4.jar:]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:330)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:220)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:303)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:45)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:73)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:336)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:189)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:155)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:139)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:91)[camel-core-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_33]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_33]

The EDI message and edi-to-xml configuration is same as given in the smooks website.
What might be the problem?
I'm using milyn-smooks-camel v1.4 and milyn-smooks-core v1.5.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your EDI file look like? Can you post that?

Comment: Actually the problem was not with the EDI file. The configuration was written in two files, one with medi tags for mapping and the other one pointing this file as mapping model. There I gave the file name only (as both were in the same directory). When I gave the full path, it's working.